# Why is there 'dereference of possible null exception' warning when null check result is assigned to variable?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable-reference-types

Working on enabling the feature to treat nullable warnings as errors and I am running into scenarios like below where I am getting `CS8602: Dereference of possibly null reference` warning.

```
List<string>? a = null;
var wasCreated = a != null;
//if (a != null) // using this doesnt give the warning
if (wasCreated) // using this gives the warning
{
    a.Add("b"); // Warning happens here.
}
```

Reading through the docs I didn't see any explicit statement calling out assigning null check result in variable and checking variable would not suffice. Is the compiler really incapable of identifying null check has happened when done that way?

Comment: Your compiler expectations are too high

Comment: I cannot repro the problem in VS2022 with `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in my project file.  When I remove it, I get `CS8632: The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' annotations context`, which is not the same warning.

Comment: @jwdonahue remove the second `if`. The example is a bit convoluted because it shows both working and non-working code in one snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known limitation of current compiler. Introducing an intermediate variable will "break" the nullable flow analysis since compiler does not perform any kind of alias/value tracking in this case (due to potential cost in both performance and implementation as far as I understand).

From [this github comment](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/34800#issuecomment-776353516):

> Closing **as we've decided not to do this type of dependent/alias flow analysis in the compiler**.

Or [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/36014#issuecomment-497055557):

> This is essentially asking for nullable to support alias tracking. That is a feature we've explicitly decided to not do in 8.0 due to the complexity. I have some doubts we'd ever be able to do it because of the inherent complexity of alias tracking in C#.
> Primary bug tracking this is #34644. Yes that is about indexers but it's the same fundamental problem: alias/value tracking.

And several others similar - [one](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/38561), [two](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/48354#issuecomment-703997594), [three](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/7675). Also [this commend about "path-independent flow analysis"](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/36927#issuecomment-508595947) is related too as far as I understand.